# Sleep laptop when power button is pressed in Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu

I recently installed lubuntu in my laptop. Right now when i press the power button my laptop shuts down. What is want is, when i press the power button it should go to sleep mode and not shut down. I found that sleep is equivalent to suspend in lubuntu so what i did is i changed settings in power manager. Here is a screenshot.

[image]

But it doesn't work, everytime i press the power button laptop shutdown instead of going to suspend mode. 
How do i make my laptop go to sleep when power button is pressed.

I even changed the logind.conf file by making HandlePowerKey to suspend, it doesn't work too. Here is a screenshot.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kSK6.png)